# Alfresco login page bypassing

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I created a valid ticket using a webservice call...code shown below

```
$url="http://serverip:port/alfresco/service/api/login?u=xxx&pw=xxx";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
$response =curl_exec($ch);
```

Now using this ticket i want to authenticate alfresco without again entering username and password.Also i want to create a valid cookie JSESSIONID inside browser with this ticket...Is it feasible??

my purpose is to integrate a php application with alfresco....php application already has an authentication system...so i want to bypass the authentication of alfresco

Comment: Do you want to login into alfresco explorer using this ticket?

Comment: yes...Naman... using this ticket of the user i want to see the user's dashboard while i hit the alfresco home page link... (it should bypass the login page)

Comment: can you tell us your main purpose?As the purpose of authentication ticket is of rest api kind of thing , and not for login in alfresco.

Comment: my purpose is to integrate a php application with alfresco....php application  already have a authentication system...so i want to bypass the authentication of alfresco

Comment: alfresco provides some inbuilt api using webscripts.You can use that using alf_ticket, which you can call.

Comment: As per my understanding you can not login without authenticating, instead use webScript API to access content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i resolved the issue by calling the login page url http://ip:port/share/page/ via Curl with login parameters(username and pwd)...I got JsessionId as response from curl...Now i took that JsessionId and set inside the browser...so wen u click http://ip:port/share/page/  the login page is bypassed

Comment: As per your suggestion, we are tried with below curl call but their is no JsessionId in response. can you please check and let me know the resolution

 `$post = [`
     `'username' => 'user',`
    ` 'password' => 'pass',`
 `];`
 `$ch = curl_init('http://ip:port/share/page/dologin/');`
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);`
 `$response = curl_exec($ch);`
 `curl_close($ch);`
 `var_dump($response);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to append below parameter

> alf_ticket="TICKET_WHICH_YOU_GET"

for further authentication.

Answer (score 0):

As per your suggestion, we are tried with below curl call but their is no JsessionId in response. can you please check and let me know the resolution

```
$post = [
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass',
];

$ch = curl_init('http://ip:port/share/page/dologin/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

// execute!
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// close the connection, release resources used
curl_close($ch);

// do anything you want with your response
var_dump($response);
```

please suggest with the solution